# Expected value of product of 2 correlated random vectors

Tags: random-vector

Let **x** and **y** be complex Gaussian random vectors with length L, and  $\mathbb{E}[x]=a$ and $\mathbb{E}[y]=b$, and they are correlated such that $c = \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\mathbf{\mathit{\mathbf{x}}}^{T}\mathbf{y}\right|\right]$

Can we write   $\mathbb{E}[|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}|^2]=Var(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y})+\mathbb{E}[|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}|]^2$   $?$ Hence,

$$\mathbb{E}|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}|^2]=Var(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y})+c^2$$

Then, can we derive an analytical expression for $Var(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y})$  or  $\mathbb{E}|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}|^2]$) ?

Comment: Have you first attempted the simpler problem of the expected value of the product of two univariate random variables? If not, I believe you will find that helpful.

Comment: Thank you Glen, I have tried. Nevertheless, I derived an approximation based on this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76961/variance-of-product-of-2-independent-random-vector and it seems working according to simulation results.